# How to solve Memory Error while loading English Module using spacy?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have imported spacy package to load english module as follows:

```
    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
    text = "London is the most populous city of United Kingdom."
    # Parse the text with spaCy. This runs the entire pipeline.
    doc = nlp(text)
```

Expected result is doc should contain parsed version of text while I am getting the following error while loading English module using spacy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/MachineLearning_NLP/First.py", line 5, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 21, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 114, in load_model
    return load_model_from_package(name, **overrides)
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 135, in load_model_from_package
    return cls.load(**overrides)
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_lg\__init__.py", line 12, in load
    return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 173, in load_model_from_init_py
    return load_model_from_path(data_path, meta, **overrides)
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 156, in load_model_from_path
    return nlp.from_disk(model_path)
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 647, in from_disk
    util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 511, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 635, in <lambda>
    self.vocab.from_disk(p) and _fix_pretrained_vectors_name(self))),
  File "vocab.pyx", line 380, in spacy.vocab.Vocab.from_disk
  File "vectors.pyx", line 391, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.from_disk
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 511, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "vectors.pyx", line 384, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.from_disk.load_vectors
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 440, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\MachineLearning_NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 704, in read_array
    array = numpy.fromfile(fp, dtype=dtype, count=count)
MemoryError
```

Comment: 'en_core_web_lg' is a large model. How much RAM does your computer have? There simply may not be enough of it.

Comment: My computer's RAM is 8gb. I think it must be sufficient.

Comment: Use 'en_core_web_sm' instead , its a pretty good model too.

Comment: 8GB should be plenty to work. This seems like an issue with numpy/spacy. Can you try a new virtual env where you install spacy and numpy as a fresh install?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your code snippet that you load file into a function and and called it again, it will collect a big garbage of data every time you call that function.
Also instead of lg data use `en_core_web_sm`.